# www prefix gives an error while not using it is fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I have in the iis 7  bindings listed for www.smartypix.com and smartypix.com

the issue is that this works
   http://smartypix.com/Anon/album/tester

but this does not 
http://www.smartypix.com/Anon/album/tester

the same code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your DNS entries - smartypix.com and www.smartypix.com resolve to different IP addresses. You're hitting different websites.

Comment: yes but it is my 1and1 account for both pointing to the same machine. i just switched the domain (with www.) from one site on the same box to this one which very different. interesting. Because the rest of the site is the same. and show the edits I do to either (www.)smartypix.com